# SSRS on screen preview vs on print preview

Tags: printing, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have SSRS report with many rows
When I print it, it looks nice, rows are split into multiple pages, each page has its number, that's what I want.

but when I click "View Report" button the report show up on screen with all rows in the same page and i have only one page.

Is there anyway I can make it looks like exactly how it will be printed when user click on "View Report" button

in another words I want the on screen preview to be A4 width and size

I changed the Interactive Size and Page Size, still getting all records in 1 page on the screen.

I am using SSRS 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display a fixed number of rows per page for an SSRS report, follow these steps:

1. Add a new **Parent Group** to the existing top level group row.
2. Type *=CEILING(RowNumber(Nothing)/50)* in the **Group by** expression. 
   *50 is the number of rows you want to show up on each page*.
3. Click **OK** to create the Parent Group.
4. Right click on the **Parent Group** that you have just created and select **Group Properties**.
5. On the **Page Breaks** tab, select **Between each instance of a group**
6. On the **Sorting** tab, delete all the sorting options shown.
7. Click **OK** to confirm the changes to the Parent Group.
8. Lastly, right click on the **Parent Group** and select **Delete Columns only**.

Please click here: [for more detailed instructions with screenshots](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3493/display-a-fixed-number-of-rows-per-page-for-an-ssrs-report/).